# Systemverilog: is there a limit in size for a dynamic array?

Tags: arrays, system-verilog, dynamic-arrays

When doing `new[SIZE]` to a dynamic array, is there a limit for the `SIZE` we can use in Systemverilog?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The limit is very big.

IEEE Std 1800-2017, section *7.5.1 New[ ]* states

```
[ expression ]:
The desired size of the dynamic array. The type of this operand is longint. 
It shall be an error if the value of this operand is negative.
```

`longint` is 64-bit signed.

Answer (score 0):

The LRM section 7.4.2 Unpacked arrays says

> Implementations may limit the maximum size of an array, but they shall allow at least 16 777 216 (2<sup>24</sup>) elements.

But you might be limited more by time than space if you tried to access that many elements. An associative array might be a better choice for a large array if you only plan to access a small percentage of the address space.

Comment: Hey @dave_59, will we start getting "junk" data when reaching to large sizes of dynamic array? We pass these arrays to "DPI-C" function which is used by a C++ code.

Comment: SystemVerilog will never allocate arrays without initializing them first; there will never be _junk_.